# Is one's percentage ranking for a specific subject tag available?

Tags: support, tags, profile-page

My user profile tells me that I am in the ***top 0.12% overall***

Is the corresponding figure for specific subject tags also available?

Of course the figure has very little meaning, but I want to use it for self-promotion in the jobs market

Comment: On your developer story it tells you which tags you're in the top 1, 5 or 10% for.

Comment: Both of these comments are interesting, but I was hoping for a figure lower than 0.12% to indicate my top subject, whereas these show nothing more accurate than 1%. However the link from @RobertLongson does indicate that I am the second from top contributor so I can boast about that! Thank you.

Comment: You could adjust the query to provide more significant figures if you need to. You can also see on the [top user's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/topusers) page that you're #2

Comment: [SEDE query for all your tags, and with higher precision](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/844823/top-percentile-values-for-a-given-user-in-all-of-his-eligible-tags).